# iPhone - Copy Mutable Array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

I am trying to create a search box to go with my UITableView, I am currently loading a JSON request into NSDictionaries and then using that to populate my table (all working fine)

I am using a second array of data to perform the search on from the search ba, but find that I cannot copy my original array.

This is my code, and the debug output:

```
NSDictionary * root = [responseString JSONValue];
//NSLog(root);

sortedArryData = [root objectForKey:@"add"];
NSLog(@"%@",sortedArryData);

[arryData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:sortedArryData];
NSLog(@"New: ");
NSLog(@"%@",arryData);
```

Output:

```
2011-12-12 21:24:39.264 app[18766:11603] Run
2011-12-12 21:24:40.677 app[18766:11603] (
    {
    address = "15 Southampton Road";
},
    {
    address = "Meeting House Lane";
}
)
2011-12-12 21:24:40.709 app[18766:11603] New: 
2011-12-12 21:24:40.709 app[18766:11603] (null)
```

Is there something i'm missing? both arryData and sortedArryData as NSMutableArray

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have not initialized arryData, right before adding to the array go ahead and initialize it like so:

```
arryData = [NSMutableArray array];
[arryData arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:sortedArryData];
```

**EDIT:**

Try this instead:

```
arryData = [NSMutableArray array];
[arryData addObject:sortedArryData];
```

Comment: I can only assume this is the problem. Even an empty (non-null) array wouldn't have printed "(null)" to the console.

Comment: I now receive the following - having added the above line:

 2011-12-13 14:08:19.954 app[19511:11603] New: 

 2011-12-13 14:08:19.954 app[19511:11603] (

 )

Comment: I have edited the response, try it and see if the results are better.

Comment: Thanks. I received "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" with addObject, but addObjectFromArray: sortedArryData - worked. Many Thanks